# Keyboard shortcut for opening the terminal in the current directory?

Tags: command-line, 22.04, gnome-terminal, shortcuts, zsh

I would like to have a keyboard shortcut that opens a terminal in the current directory.

Here is what I already did:

1. `open_terminal_here.sh`:

```
#!/bin/zsh
gnome-terminal --working-directory="$PWD" -- zsh
```

2. and then added these lines in `~/.zshrc`:

```
chmod +x ~/open_terminal_here.sh
```

and then sourced it. It does work in the terminal (so the command is configured correctly) but when I keybind something to it, it just doesn't work. Any workarounds for this?

Comment: **Note:** Once you run `chmod +x ~/open_terminal_here.sh` there is no need to have that line in `~/.zshrc`

Comment: It's not clear what this question is asking. I originally thought that you wanted a keyboard shortcut in the files app to open terminal. However do you agree with the 2 answerers that this question is about opening *another* terminal window (not tab) while *already* in a terminal window?

Comment: @DanielT Since OP has "and then added these lines in `~/.zshrc`" and given rc files like `~/.zshrc` are normally only sourced by interactive shells like in a terminal emulator, I would say it’s pretty much OP wants that behavior in a terminal … I think … Plus GUI file managers usually have that capability as a builtin right click menu option "open in terminal" already.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now what behavior the OP desired. What I will never understand is *why* they desire it, because I just press CTRL+SHIFT+T to open a new tab in the current directory

Comment: @DanielT One thing that I can tell from OP contents is they want the freedom of choosing the new terminal's shell by setting it in that command after `--`  and possibly maybe other customization as well.

Comment: OP I think you created an infinite loop, didn't you? You open a terminal, it executes the default shell (I assume it's zsh for you), which in its startup files ask to open a terminal which again executes zsh which again calls that script that will open a terminal etc...

Answer (score 5):

`PWD` is a shell variable that is dynamically set in any specific shell instance as you `cd`/traverse your filesystem hierarchy ... It needs to be expanded by the same shell instance at the same present working directory in order to reflect that exact state ... and for that, your key-shortcut/key-binding needs to be handled by that specific running interactive shell and not by any other external means like DE shortcut-keys/hot-keys handlers.

That said, `zsh` has a [`bindkey`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-bindkey) builtin command that you can use like:

```
bindkey -s '^E' 'gnome-terminal --working-directory="$PWD" -- zsh\n'
```

... to set a shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> <sup>**1**</sup> to launch a new `gnome-terminal` window with `zsh` as its shell in `PWD`.

Similarly, `bash` has a [`bind`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-bind.) builtin command that you can use like:

```bash
bind -x '"\C-E":gnome-terminal --working-directory="$PWD" -- zsh'
```

**Notice** that those commands might be added to the end of each shell's rc file e.g. either `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` for Zsh and Bash respectively so that the key-binding gets automatically set each time a new **interactive** shell is started like when opening a new `gnome-terminal` window for instance.

---

**1**) Notice that some key-bindings are already in use either by your shell or by the terminal emulator it runs in ... So, check and make sure you don't use any of those to avoid conflicts

Answer (score 5):

Here are some default terminal keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: To open a new *tab* in the current directory
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>: To open a new *window* in the current directory

This works by default on both `gnome-terminal` and `konsole`. It is not necessary to manually add anything in `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: (gnome-terminal developer here) Yes, this is how to open a new terminal from an existing terminal (assuming that this is the question). No need for tricky fiddling with cmdline parameters as in other answers. Note that in gnome-terminal, in order for this to work you need to source `/etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh` (or whatever similar the exact filename is) in your bash or zsh startup files. Your system should be set up by default to automatically do this, but if you tamper with your shell configs then you might stop it from happening.